# Remove zeros from a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix with large rows and columns as follows:

```
A = 0    0  0  0 
    0    0  0  0 
    0    0  0  0 
    2000 11 16 -0.74
    0    0  0  0
    0    0  0  0
    2000 12 26 -0.84
    0    0  0  0
    0    0  0  0
```

I need to remove all the zeros from the matrix to get output like,

```
B = 2000 11 16 -0.74
    2000 12 26 -0.84
```

I have tried an available solution over here like,

```
B = A(A~=0)
```

It removes zeros but gives output like,

```
2000
2000
11
12
-0.74
-0.84
```

How to get the desired output?

Comment: What if there are rows that contain zeros and nonzeros? How should the nonzero entries be arranged in the output?

Answer (score 3):

assuming `A` is a two dimensional matrix

```
A(any(A,2),:)
```

will do.

Example:

```
>> A=[rand(2,3); zeros(3); rand(1,3)]
A =

   0.13878   0.44315   0.25832
   0.01879   0.93844   0.57537
   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
   0.50581   0.37870   0.56563

>> A(any(A,2),:)
ans =

   0.138776   0.443152   0.258325
   0.018794   0.938439   0.575371
   0.505809   0.378696   0.565632
```

Comment: what did you try? what didn't work?  Can you try the example I posted?

Comment: Sir I tried this example. Matrix A is generated as shown but not the output (matrix with nonzeros).